# web2py ajax issue onclick

Tags: python, html, ajax, web2py

I am trying to write a controller method and a corresponding view which will call the controller on web2py using Ajax. The idea is to make a small update on the database and return a simple updated message on a target div using Ajax. Below is contoller method:

```
def deleteajax():
recid1 = request.vars.recid
reptype1 = request.vars.reptype
if recid1 == None:
    out = 'Missing Param : recid'
    return out
if reptype1 == None:
    reptype1 = 'pr'        
if reptype1 == 'pr':
    row = db2(db2.prs_mailed.id==recid1).select().first()
    return str(row.id)
elif reptype1 == 'tb':
    row = db2(db2.tbs_mailed.id==recid1).select().first()
else:
    return 'Please provide the parameter : rep'
if row['action'] == 'D':
    out = 'Already deleted'
    return out
else:
    row.update_record(action='D')
    out = 'Deleted Successfully!'
    return out
```

and this is how I am calling the same from view:

```
     <form>{{
     response.write('<input type="hidden" name="recid" value="'+str(response._vars['prs']['id'][k])+'"/>',escape=False)}}
     <input type ='button' name="del" value = "D"  onclick="ajax('deleteajax', ['reid'], 'target')" />
     <div id="target"></div>
     </form>
```

I have tested the controller individually using a POST call and that works. Even the AJAX call works and displays error messages like 'Missing Param : recid' on the target div. I even tried modifying the controller to show more messages after finishing each statement. However, post any database operation, no commands from the controller are getting executed, nor is anything showed on the target div. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of this:

```
{{response.write('<input type="hidden" name="recid" value="' +
    str(response._vars['prs']['id'][k])+'"/>',escape=False)}}
```

Just do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recid" value="{{=prs['id'][k])}}"/>
```

There's no need to use response.write or to access the "prs" object through response._vars (all the items in response._vars are available globally in the view environment).

Regarding the Ajax problem, your input element name is "recid", but your `ajax()` call refers to "reid". Change the latter to "recid" and see if it works.

UPDATE:

To create multiple unique recid's, you could do:

```
name="{{='recid%s' % prs['id'][k]}}"
```

Then, in the controller, check for request.vars that start with "recid":

```
recid = [v for v in request.post_vars if v.startswith('recid')]
if recid:
    recid = int(recid[0][5:])
    [code to delete record with id==recid]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have removed the response.write part and changed it as you had mentioned improving the readability. The reid was on purpose so that it least prints the error message of missing parameter from the controller, which it did.

Comment: I finally deduced the cause of this behaviour to be because I have many other inputs named recid in the html file, and while passing it to the controller it passes a list of values of all of these. I am printing this view part for a list of items, each of which have this form with the same input control name. Could you help me with How can I make this unique and refer the same from controller? is a combination of ajax and javascript possible on the click event of the same button on web2py?

Comment: Maybe just give each input a unique name: `name="{{='recid%s' % prs['id'][k]}}"`. In the controller, you can just check for response.vars that start with "recid".

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Shall try that!

Comment: Could you guide me on how to check for all response.vars that start with recid? I tried using things like request.args[0] on the controller, but they fail to work. Is there a way in which I could list down all request vars? sorry about the simple questions, I am a beginner with web2py and couldn't get an answer from google for these.

Comment: `request.args` stores args from the URL, not vars. See updated answer for a possible solution.